# PHP setcookie fails

Tags: php, cookies

I narrowed the problem down to this statement.

```
if (!setcookie("cookielogin",$usernametocheck, time()+3600)) echo "cookie setup failed<br/>";
```

Every time I run the code it shows "cookie setup failed" on browser.

I checked the browser for cookies stored by the site and I don't see my cookie.

Can anybody help ?

Comment: make sure . the output is not started before creating cookie .

Comment: Yes, I had few output lines before for reference. And I removed them. Still I am getting the same error. Don't see the cookie in the browser cookie list.

Comment: Manual says: *If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE.* There doesn't seem to be another documented possibility.

Answer (score 0):

add `ob_start();` at the top of your page and `ob_clean()` after setting cookie .

```
<?php
ob_start();
#Code..........
#Code...........
#Code............   
if (!setcookie("cookielogin",$usernametocheck, time()+3600)) echo "cookie setup failed<br/>";
ob_clean();
#code......

?>
```